# Conditional Formatting for highlighting cells based on values in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want a formula that will highlight a cell in column G based on a range of numbers (lets say, numbers between 888 and 1000) in column E?

Comment: Can you show an example of your Data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=AND(E2>=888,E2<=1000)
```

- Select column G
- Conditional Formatting
- New Rule
- Use a Formula to determine which cells to Format
- Write the above formula in the box
- Format as you like
- Ok

Comment: That's Awesome Thank you, it worked perfectly

Comment: If you are satisfied just accept the answer